# Genson failed to serialize in JDK7

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, genson

I have a JAX-RS client which is as follow:

```
MyObj myObj = new MyObj();
myObj .setRemark("My test case");
myObj .setSomeDate( LocalDate.now());
...

 WebResource webResource = client
            .resource("my_url");

    webResource
            .header("apikey", "mykey")
            .accept("application/json")
            .type("application/json")
            .post(MyObj.class, myObj );
```

Evrything works fine for JDK8. But then when I switched to JDK7, it starts giving this error: `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.owlike.genson.JsonBindingException: Failed to serialize object of type class MyObj`

I am using Genson v1.4. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Java 7 is obsolete.